# the checkbox ng-model is not changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10211/

```
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings_channel" ng-checked="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-disabled="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN">A
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.settings.channel.READ" ng-checked="settings_channel || permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-disabled="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN">B
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.settings.channel.WRITE" ng-checked="settings_channel || permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-disabled="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN">C
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-checked="settings_channel">D
</label>
```

I want when a user check A or D, B and C is disabled.

but that source don't execute.

if I choose D I can see what I want.

but when I choose A, D value is not changed so B and C is not disabled.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings_channel" ng-checked="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-disabled="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN">A
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.settings.channel.READ" ng-checked="settings_channel || permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-disabled="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN || settings_channel">B
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.settings.channel.WRITE" ng-checked="settings_channel || permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-disabled="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN || settings_channel">C
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.settings.channel.ADMIN" ng-checked="settings_channel">D
</label>
```

i added the `A` option `|| settings_channel` the same as saying `A` or `D`, assuming `settings_channel` its a boolean, it has to if its in a checkbox.